# Design of buck boost converter

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, comparator, mosfet-driver

I'm implementing a buck boost converter. I need a variabe duty cycle with constant frequency of 200kHz(without using a ardino board in which I suppose I would have to upload a program everytime to get a new duty cycle ) to drive the igbt. I was thinking if using a opm comparator with one input as Vref with a potentiometer to get variable duty cycle and  another input as a constant frequency sawtooth wave from microcontroller . But can i  give such high frequency wave to opm in the first place n get a decent pwm signal? Isnt there another way ?

Comment: There is a tool to draw circuits, it would be advantagues to improve you question by drawing a nice, good looking circuit

Comment: There are hundreds of switching controller ICs available that will do most of the hard work for you.

Comment: As suggested by @laptop2d draw your circuit. If you tell us your input and output requirements we can probably suggest a suitable control IC, Linear Tech make quite a good range.

Answer (score 2):

> Isnt there another way ?

You can always buy an off the shelf solution such as the LTC6992: -

[image]

Inside the chip is pretty much what you have described for what you believe is necessary for building one.

Comment: I'll definitely try with this IC. Thank you so much for ur help..!